# Restrict who can call a constructor

Tags: solidity, constructor

I create an instance of a child contract using a Factory contract. I want to limit the constructor of the child to only be called by the Factory. Is this possible?

```js
contract Factory {

  function createChildInstance public {
    Child child = new Child();
  };
}
```

```js
contract Child is Ownable {
  constructor() onlyOwner {
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you hide the `createChildInstance` function behind [access control](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control).

Anyone can copy the deployed code anyways, so I don`t think it makes much sense trying to protect it.